# Model-specific (e.g. Dell) memory: Differences to normal RAM?

Tags: memory, oem

I know that it is probably more expensive because they're officially tested and supported, but I'm wondering if model-specific memory is "special" apart from that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically they are not. We always run our HP servers with bog standard RAM from whatever vendor. There are a few pitfalls though:

Some vendors use "convincors" to make you fork out extorionate prices - for example you lose the "HP Smart Memory" feature (whatever good this does).

Not all vendors are honest with their specs - double and triple check, that your Rank count, registered/registered, etc. match what you actually have, not what the vendor says.

Answer (score 1):

The normal answer is no. The only real difference is they can/will blame any 3rd party items you insert without their consent.. So, I bought non Dell memory for my laptop, runs like a charm.  However, if you get a fault you should revert back to their memory check it still does it and then call them out, otherwise they can often reserve the right to walk away because you may have "damaged" the system by putting non certified stuff in.